# How to install GDAL Library in Docker Python image?

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm using python3.7-slim-buster docker image for my django project. Now I want to use Geo features of django. But it seems I have to install GDAL. So, I do RUN apt-get install gdal and it raises exception "E: Unable to locate package gdal-bin".
Here is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# DB vars
ENV DB_USER_NAME ${DB_USER_NAME}
ENV DB_NAME ${DB_NAME}
ENV DB_HOST ${DB_HOST}
ENV DB_PORT ${DB_PORT}
ENV DB_PASSWORD ${DB_PASSWORD}

ENV DJANGO_SECRET_KEY ${DJANGO_SECRET_KEY}

RUN apt-get install -y gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal

RUN ["adduser", "${USER_NAME}", "--disabled-password", "--ingroup", "www-data", "--quiet"]

USER ${USER_NAME}

ADD ${PROJECT_NAME}/ /home/${USER_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}
WORKDIR /home/${USER_NAME}/${PROJECT_NAME}

ENV PATH="/home/${USER_NAME}/.local/bin:\${PATH}:/usr/local/python3/bin"

RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000
#CMD gunicorn ${PROJECT_NAME}.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

Comment: Try to call `apt-get update` before install gdal

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but, I did, it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

you need to do the following:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common && apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3.7-dev
RUN  add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa &&  apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gdal-bin libgdal-dev
ARG CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
ARG C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
RUN pip install GDAL
```

Comment: It raises add-apt-repository command not found als it is unable to locate the package python3.7-dev. Did you notice that my base image is python3.7-slim-buster? I think this commands is for ubuntu. But I want to use something light, so that my deployments don't take much time.

Comment: `apt-get install -y software-properties-common` see the update, make sure to run apt-get update also before all the thing

Comment: what that suppose to mean ?

Comment: I don't know, error log is in the link. I wasn't able to get any insights from it.

Comment: that means that you should install gpg , but that has nothing to do with your original question ......

Answer (score 5):

If you can use other base image, here is one with gdal installed:

`FROM osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-3.2.0`

Comment: Somehow pip is missing in there

Answer (score 0):

That's because your image doesn't have repository which contain gdal-bin package. So you have to add repository (you can see the guideline [here](https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/gdal-ubuntu-pkg.html)) and install it:

```
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa && apt-get update && apt-get install -y gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that I have to add the repo. But command you provided is not present as a command in this image. It raises add-apt-repository command not found.

Comment: Did you notice that my base image is python3.7-slim-buster? I think this command is for ubuntu. But I want to use something light, so that my deployments don't take much time.

Comment: So I think you should build that from source code to make the image as light as possible. You can take a look at here to see how they do https://github.com/perrygeo/docker-gdal-base