# cannot create docker for unsupportive version of GDAL==2.4.1

Tags: python, docker, pip, gdal, requirements.txt

I am trying to make  docker from a python script. I made the requirements.txt using this -

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

The Dockerfile is as below:

```
FROM python
COPY . /
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "python", "./model/deploy/main.py" ]
```

It fails at this point -

```
Collecting GDAL==2.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 42))
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement GDAL==2.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 42)
```

When I manually try to install using -

```
pip3 install GDAL==2.4.1
```

I get this -

```
Requirement already satisfied: GDAL==2.4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.4.1)
```

How can I fix the issue? I need to create the docker.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433776/how-to-install-gdal-library-in-docker-python-image/58433897#58433897

Comment: Thank you so much for your question. This gave me the idea just to check the GDAL version. After I delivered the expected minor version, my own problem was resolved (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68130787/oserror-libgdal-dylib-cannot-open-file). Truly, the simplest thing is that which comes to mind last.

Answer (score 1):

There is no [GDAL version 2.4.1 at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/#history). If you have it installed that probably means the version existed at some point in the past but later was removed by the maintainers.

Try 2.4.2 or 3.0.1.