# OSError: libgdal.dylib: cannot open file

Tags: docker, postgis, gdal, apple-m1

The problem is: Docker doesn't run properly because of `OSError: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.3.0_2/lib/libgdal.dylib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.
My current task is just to add GeoDjango to my existing Django dockerized project, with PostGIS database.  I installed postgis image with postgis/postgis.

I Butguess something went wrong because of the incorrect gdal installation. I installed gdal with Homebrew. To be honest, I do not understand why do I need gdal on my machine if I use Docker.

Now I use Big Sur OS on the MacBook Air (M1, 2020) and the last versions of all packages.

I found descriptions of a number of similar cases, but not exactly the same as mine, and the reasons are different.

I would like to figure out what kind of problem I am facing, why it occurred, and how to fix it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Details:

If I do `docker compose up`, I see a normal process beginning, and then an error:

```
(venv) [computer_name]@G-MacBook-Air-2 [project_name] % docker compose up
[+] Running 2/0
 ⠿ Container 64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 Created 0.0s
⠿ Container 0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 Created 0.0s
Attaching to 0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1, 64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | 
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | 
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | 2021-06-25 11:10:50.354 UTC [1] LOG: starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | 2021-06-25 11:10:50.358 UTC [1] LOG: listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | 2021-06-25 11:10:50.358 UTC [1] LOG: listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | 2021-06-25 11:10:50.365 UTC [1] LOG: listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | 2021-06-25 11:10:50.386 UTC [62] LOG: database system shutdown was interrupted; last known up at 2021-06-25 11:05:06 UTC
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | 2021-06-25 11:10:50.549 UTC [62] LOG: database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | 2021-06-25 11:10:50.555 UTC [62] LOG: redo starts at 0/1F45190
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | 2021-06-25 11:10:50.556 UTC [62] LOG: invalid record length at 0/1F451C8: wanted 24, got 0
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | 2021-06-25 11:10:50.556 UTC [62] LOG: redo done at 0/1F45190
64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1 | 2021-06-25 11:10:50.614 UTC [1] LOG: database system is ready to accept connections
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | Exception in thread django-main-thread:
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | self.run()
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | fn(*args, **kwargs)
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | autoreload.raise_last_exception()
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | raise _exception[1]
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | fn(*args, **kwargs)
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | app_config.import_models()
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 206, in contribute_to_class
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 214, in __getitem__
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/base.py", line 6, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | from .features import DatabaseFeatures
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/features.py", line 1, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/base/features.py", line 3, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | from django.contrib.gis.db import models
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions # NOQA
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py", line 3, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | from .fields import ( # NOQA
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 2, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 50, in <module>
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
0e8ee44abd93_[project_name]_web_1 | OSError: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.3.0_2/lib/libgdal.dylib: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

At the address '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.3.0_2/lib/libgdal.dylib' I see just a shortcut to the file libgdal.dylib. I have no idea why and do I need to fix it or it is normal.

*settings.py*:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'postgis',
        'USER': 'postgis',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgis',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

and

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.2.2_3/lib/libgdal.dylib'
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get install gdal-bin

COPY . /code/
```

My docker_compose.yaml file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgis/postgis
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - ALLOW_IP_RANGE=0.0.0.0/0
   
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code

    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

If I try to reproduce this error, sometimes some minutes later it adds something like `64a949117135_[project_name]_db_1   | CREATE EXTENSION ^[[C`  or crash message and does not continue.

Comment: The Docker container can't use libraries from your host system (especially if it's a Linux container and a MacOS host).  If you `apt-get install gdal-bin` then the libraries should be in the standard library path, and you shouldn't need to manually set `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, zsh: command not found: apt-get. Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem was resolved after I chose the `gdal` version strictly from the list suggested in the error message. Before that, I just had the latest version.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer? I am trying to solve a similar problem - did you change your ``gdal`` version in ``requirements.txt`` or somewhere else?

Comment: The answer is not clear whether i should install new gdal version in docker or in the pip environment